# Is it possible to create KeyVault using ARM, generate password and use the password in other ARM resources?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I would like to create ARM Template

1. create a resource group that contains KeyVault;
2. generate new secret with predefined name, e.g AdminPassword.
3. Use the password in other resources, e.g Master password when creating a SQL Database.

When redeploying the template and KeyVault and the AdminPassword secret already exist, existing secret should be used.

I have found samples where KeyVault secret is used as a parameter, however this is different, because KeyVault does not exist at the time parameters are resolved.

Can you write sample ARM teplate that creates KeyVault and then uses sectets from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the password in the ARM Template using [uniqueString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#uniquestring).

Then create your KeyVault and the Secret. On the outputs of the KeyVault template you can then get the URI of the Secret which can be injected into the App Configuration of another resource such as a Web App. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

```
"outputs": {
    "dbSecretUri": {
        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', parameters('keyVaultName'), 'yourSecretName')).secretUriWithVersion]"
    }
}
```

Your web app will need Managed Identity enabled and the KeyVault will need to have an Access Policy that allows that app to connect to the vault.

Answer (score 1):

if you generate a secret in an arm template - it makes no sense to retrieve it from the key vault, if you pass the secret to the template - again it makes no sense to retrieve it, just use it. either way, if you are really keen on making your life harder you can probably hack something in the arm template using conditions and nested templates

Comment: Well I need to store the passwords somewhere, right? So that for example my web app can later retrieve it in order to connect to the database

Comment: I'm not saying not using the password in the keyvault, i'm saying there's no point in retrieving it from the kv if you generate it in the template. because you already know it - if you need to put it into the kv

Comment: You are right. I was trying to automate the steps I was doing manually in azure portal

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how secure you want the password to be...

If you want a subsequent deployment to use the same password value, then it has to be deterministic.  If it's deterministic then anyone with access to the deployment can determine the password.

If you want the password to be random, then the template will generate a random one each time so a subsequent deployment would create a new password.

You *could* use a user provided seed for the password generation as a parameter (and use uniqueString() which is idempotent) and then only someone who knows the seed and has access to the deployment could determine the password.  Note that your seed would have to be a secureString parameter type.  But at this point a better practice would be to separate the steps of password generation and resource deployment.